# Sorting by the sum of values that are in relation table column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have these relation similar to that of documentation and relations are set. posts have many comments and rates. comments have many rates. It is a polymorphic relation.

```
posts
    id - integer
    user_id -integer
    body - text

comments
    id - integer
    post_id - integer
    user_id - integer
    body - string

rates
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    rate - integer
    likable_id - integer
    likable_type - string
```

How do i order the posts and comments with most rates? I get the posts and the respective rates this way.But the posts are ordered by id by default. same goes to comment.

```
$posts=Post::with('comments','comments.rates','rates')->get();
foreach($posts as $post)
{
      $post=$post->body;   //post
      foreach($post->comments as $comment)
      {
          $comment=$comment->body;      //comment
          $rateofcomment=$comment->rates->sum('rate');  //rate of comment
      }
      $rateofpost=$post->rates->sum('rate');  //rate of post
}
```

**Update**
changed in post.php and comment.php

```
public function rates()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Rate', 'likable')
                ->selectRaw('SUM(rate) as rateSum, likable_id')
                ->groupBy('likable_id');
}
```

and in rate.php

```
 public function likable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Actually this code below worked for first of the post. means if i die; the rest of foreach execution it displayed the rates.

```
$posts=Post::with('comments','comments.rates','rates')->get();
       foreach($posts as $post)
        {
              $post=$post->body;   //post
              $rateofpost = $post->rates->rateSum;
              print_r($rateofpost); die;
```

But. If i try to complete the foreach loop it displays the familiar error Trying to get property of non object? this is because all of the posts and comments may not have rateSum. How can i avoid this?

Comment: If all of your posts and comments have `rateSum` is it working fine then? Please check for this. Then we can figure out a solution for the rest of the problem. :)

Comment: @sha-1 yes. i've just checked it.

Comment: @sha-1 solved that with isset(). thanks for all your efforts,

Comment: You can also use [Laravel Accessor and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to check if the `rates` is null or not and then use a default value. But yours one will work too. Thanks for marking my answer accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be other ways to solve this. But you can use [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby) or [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortbydesc) Collection method to solve your problem.

```
$posts=Post::with('comments','comments.rates','rates')->get();
foreach($posts as $post)
{
  $post->rating = $post->rates->sum('rate');
  foreach($post->comments as $comment)
  {
      $comment->rating = $comment->rates->sum('rate');
  }
  $post->comments = $post->comments->sortByDesc('rating');
}
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('rating');
```

Here you just need to add a property to your collection using the rating values. And then sort the collections based on that rating.

**Update:**

Add the following method to your Model ***Post.php*** and ***Comment.php***.

```
public function rates()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Rate', 'likable')
                ->selectRaw('SUM(rate) as rateSum, likable_id')
                ->groupBy('likable_id');
}
```

And this following code in your Model ***Rate.php*** (If you don't already have one).

```
public function likable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Now you can code like this-

```
$posts = Post::with('comments','comments.rates','rates')->get()->sortByDesc('rates.rateSum');
foreach($posts as $post)
{
  $post=$post->body;
  $post->comments = $post->comments->sortByDesc('rates.rateSum');
  foreach($post->comments as $comment)
  {
      $comment = $comment->body;
      $rateofcomment = $comment->rates->rateSum;
  }
  $rateofpost = $post->rates->rateSum;
}
```

Comment: so again i need to use foreach to get body of posts and comments.

Comment: You can get the body of posts and comments inside this foreach. Don't need to use another foreach loop.

Comment: body of posts and comments sorted by rating inside this foreach. can you show by editing  the answer.

Comment: Do you need to use body of posts and comments inside this foreach?? Or you need to use them later? if you need to use them later, then they are already sorted. I'm not sure why you might need them inside this foreach loop.

Comment: yes. I need inside this foreach along with their rates.

Comment: Then you might need to run another foreach loop, i think.

Comment: Have you looked at [constraining](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) the `with()` parameters.

Comment: @sha-1 tried exactly that. got undefined property rateSum. And why morphOne?

Comment: @micky, I've created a demo app using your database and tested on that. It worked fine. Could you please check your Database and Models if they are okay? We could have use `morphMany` instead of `morphOne`, but then the rates relation will return a **Collection Array**. using morphOne will ensure that it will only return a single Collection, as we won't need an array, we just need the SUM value.

Comment: I'm not sure what but with morphOne, here `$comment->rates->rateSum` exactly is the error: trying to get property of undefined. and with morphMany rateSum simply is undefined property. just opposite of what i thought it should be.

Comment: Can you update your question with your Models code for `Post`', `Comment` and `Rate`?

Comment: updated and actually it worked for first post but not for foreach,